# MSSQLSERVICE 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, visual-studio

I have Microsoft SQL Server 2008 installed and running but I can't seem to see `COMPUTERNAME/MSSQLSERVICE` at all.

I have `COMPUTERNAME/SQLEXPRESS` but that's not the right one.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

So looks like you need to check all instances of sql server running and available. You can check then what if the name is correct or the service is running.

Two ways you could approach this:

If you have Sql Server Management Studio installed:

- If the `Connect to Server` Dialog is not visible goto `File > Connect Object Explorer`
- Expand the server name dropdown and select `Browse for more`
- In the `Browse for Servers` dialog, check the Network servers tab and expand `DataBase engine`.

OR

Use `osql.exe`, it's located here : `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn`

and do:

```
osql -L
```

Answer (score 0):

The chances are that the full SQL Server instance on the machine is the default instance, therefore to access it you don't need to specify an instance name.

Therefore, use `COMPUTERNAME` to access this instance, rather than `COMPUTERNAME/MSSQLSERVICE`.

If unsure, [use OSQL to list instances](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1113/find-sql-servers-on-your-network-with-osql-and-sqlcmd/) on the machine.